# Pressing charges for an unlawful car seizure

Tags: united-kingdom, civil-procedure

I was given a 28 day to proceed with a civil complaint against the local police force due to an unlawful vehicle seizure. Preparing for the worst, I have recorded all my communication with them, which contain vital information. My question is, can I use call/voice recordings as evidence in UK courts?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you tell the local police men that you were recording?

Comment: "There is no general rule that excludes evidence because it has been obtained in a covert manner. The court recognised the evidential value of covert recordings in Singh v Singh [2016] EWCH 1432 (Ch) [..] there is no general rule that evidence must be excluded simply because it has been obtained illegally or improperly. The court will consider how the evidence was obtained, its relevance and probative value (Mustard v Flower [2019] EWHC 2623 (QB))" - https://www.lewissilkin.com/en/insights/covert-recordings-does-use-in-court-justify-the-risk

Answer (score 4):

> can I use call/voice recordings as evidence in UK courts?

Yes. At least at evidentiary hearings. In pre-hearing motions, you may need to have a transcript prepared and authenticated.